# How do I show a simple AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to Display `AlertDialog` from my class. Program flow is working fine, because i am able to Display Toast message properly. However, the dialog never shows up? Why is this happening? I am not getting any error message in logs and/or no application crash is found. What may be reason for this behavior.

I have given the required permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Please refer my code :

```
if (serverApkVersion > localApkVersion) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Are you sure?")
            .create();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    alertDialog.show();
    Toast.makeText(context, "toast is working, but dialog is not >:(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "up to date!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: You missed one line of code is : alertDialog.create();

Comment: for using `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`, since MM, the user has to explicitly allow your app to draw over other apps. That means you can´t start a runtime permission and it isn´t enough to add this permission in manifest. The only thing you can do is to start the system settings page from your device to let the user give this permission.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("title");
        builder.setMessage("message");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //do your action
            }
        });       
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //do your action
            }
        });
        builder.show();
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your answer, but can you explain what does it do differently than mine?

Comment: You should trigger a click event or some intent to open a dialog box.please show your code..

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example:

```
  public static void showAlert(String msg, final Context context) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle("Alert").
                setMessage(msg).
                setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }
```

For your code, you have take permission from user.

Answer (score 0):

[image]  Just Replace Your `AlertDialog` with `AlertDialog.Builder` and you are good to go.

```
if (serverApkVersion > localApkVersion) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Checking.this)
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure?");
                     alertDialog.show();
        Toast.makeText(context, "toast is working, but dialog is not >:(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "up to date!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `AlertDialog` code seems OK. I guess the problem is about the wrong `Context` that you used to create an `instance` of `AlertDialog.Builder`.

**Use:**

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
```

**Instead of:**

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

**Update your code as below:**

```
if (serverApkVersion > localApkVersion) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Are you sure?")
            .create();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    alertDialog.show();
    Toast.makeText(context, "toast is working, but dialog is not >:(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "up to date!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**FYI,** If your app running on Android 6.0+ then you should add run-time permission for `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`.

See [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/24/system-alert-window-now-more-hidden-than-ever.html) for details.

Hope this will help~